# Firebase save function error when updating database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update my price, and I keep getting this error upon clicking the <kbd>Save</kbd> button. This is the error code I'm getting:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined 
> at updatePrice (settings.js:52:43) 
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM148 settings.html:284:132)

I have provided my JavaScript code below. This is how I'm calling my function in HTML as well:

```html
<button class="priceSave" type="submit" id="save11" value="save11" onclick="updatePrice()">Save</button>
```

JavaScript code *updated*:

```javascript
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize variables
const database = firebase.database();
const auth = firebase.auth();

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {console.log(user);});


function updatePrice() {
    // Get data
    numberInput = document.getElementById("numberInput").value;

    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    // Enter database location
    firebase
        .database()
        .ref(user.uid + "/prices/roomA/serviceOne")
        .update({

            //studioName : studioName,
            numberInput: numberInput,
        });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of fact, `user` is not defined in the `updatePrice()` function. In your code, it's only within the callback function passed to the `onAuthStateChanged()` observer that `user` is defined.

You need to use the `currentUser` property as follows:

```
function updatePrice() {
    //Get data
    numberInput = document.getElementById("numberInput").value;

    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    //Enter database location
    firebase
        .database()
        .ref("/studiopick/studio/users" + user.uid + "/prices/roomA/serviceOne")
        .update({

            //studioName : studioName,
            numberInput: numberInput,
        });
}
```

---

However, you need to take into account that `currentUser` could be `null`. This can happen if the `auth` object has not finished initializing (more information by reading the **entire** following [documentation section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)).

So, for example, before calling this function, check that `firebase.auth()` is not null. If it is the case, you can retry in some few seconds or indicate the user to try later.

Comment: Yep, it just came back null

Comment: Do you mean `user` is `null` with the code from my answer?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')

Comment: Also, one last thing. I'm trying to save their price under the uid that's logged in, but it doesn't save it properly. It saves the price outside of the uid

Comment: The problem most probably comes from the fact the user is not signed in. What do you have if you add a `console.log()` as follows: `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {console.log(user); ...});`

Comment: This is what gets returned in the console:  lh

Comment: I'm guessing that is the user that's logged in

Comment: I updated my function above to what I currently have

Comment: If you add `console.log(user);`in the callback function of the `onAuthStateChanged()` listener and received "lh" then you have a problem of user signingin. You should get a JavaScript object. can you check you added excatly like I advise in my last comment.

Comment: Still getting lh with the exact function you used

Comment: I just updated my code again to show exactly what I have